# add items to complicated data-struc `Map<String, Map<String,String>>`

Tags: java, data-structures

I have the following complex data-structure:

```
Map<String, Map<String,String>> URL_and_entities = new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();
```

on the inside of a loop I finally want to populate it but I can't figure out how.

This is my code, it's essentially a series of nested loops that make an HTTP request to determine if they share a relationship, which is revealed by the presence (or absence) of a url. I'm trying to save the URL (if it exists), and the two entities that evoked it:

```
for (String entity_1 : Q_value_references_for_sentence_entities) 
{

  for (String entity_2 : Q_value_references_for_sentence_entities) 
  {

        String URL_czech = "http://milenio.dcc.uchile.cl/sparql?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX+%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0D%0ASELECT+*+WHERE+%7B%0D%0A+++%3A" 
                           + entity_1 + "+%3FsimpleProperty+%3A" 
                           + entity_2 + "%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on";

        URL wikidata_page = new URL(URL_czech);
        HttpURLConnection wiki_connection = (HttpURLConnection)wikidata_page.openConnection();
        InputStream wikiInputStream = null;

        try 
        {
            // try to connect and use the input stream
            wiki_connection.connect();
            wikiInputStream = wiki_connection.getInputStream();
        } 
        catch(IOException error) 
        {
            // failed, try using the error stream
            wikiInputStream = wiki_connection.getErrorStream();
        }
        // parse the input stream using Jsoup
        Document docx = Jsoup.parse(wikiInputStream, null, wikidata_page.getProtocol()+"://"+wikidata_page.getHost()+"/");


        Elements link_text = docx.select("table.sparql > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > a");
        //link_text.text();
        for (Element l : link_text) 
        {
            String output = l.text();
            output = output.substring(0, output.length()-1);
            list_of_relation_URLs.add( output );

            URL_and_entities.put( output , (entity_1, entity_2));
        }
    }           
}
```

I'm not oppoed to using that crazy google library of wonky data-strucs, I've used it before, but in this case I can't see a compelling reason why it would be any better than `Map<String, Map<String,String>>`

---

**Update**

I'm having trouble getting the values out. This doesn't work it seems

```
String first__english_lang_Q = retrieved_entities.getKey();
String second_english_lang_Q = retrieved_entities.getValue();

System.out.println("`(" + value + ")'" + "`( " + entity_1 + ", " + entity_2 + ")'");
```

Comment: Number 1: try reading the javadoc.  You add to a map with `put`, not `add`.  Number 2: you populate the map the way you would populate any map, with `put(key,value)`, except that your `value` here will be another map, which you will also populate with `put(key,value)`.

Comment: but this `URL_and_entities.put( output , (entity_1, entity_2));` is wrong

Comment: Because `(entity_1, entity_2)` is not a map.  [And it wasn't in your question until after I typed in my comment.]  Actually, it's not anything except illegal Java.  Create a `Map<String,String>`, populate it using `put`, and then use the map as the value when adding to the larger map.

Comment: should i create a new map every time within the inner innner loop?

Comment: Yes, create a new map, unless you want your keys in the large map pointing to the _exact_ same map as a value.

Comment: great! you're awesome!

Comment: how can i iterate that beast tho. `for (String url : URL_and_entities.getKey()) ` is not working

Comment: I assume it's "not working" because the compiler said there's no `getKey` method?  The answer is to read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead of trying to guess the method names.

Comment: @ajb what a about using Map.Entry instead of creating a new map?

Comment: @ajb OP just put one pair in every iteration in his hash map, so I think we could simply use a Map.Entry instead of creating a new map in every iteration

Comment: @Lrrr Try writing the code for this.  You will pretty quickly find out that this doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ajb I'm having trouble getting the values back out again. I put what Ive been trying in a **update** to the OP

Comment: @Lrrr Oh, crikey, I see what you were trying to do.  And it's very bad.  That is not what `Map.Entry` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a tuple, You can use the apache common [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)

```
Map<String, Pair<String,String>> URL_and_entities = new HashMap<String, Pair<String,String>>();

URL_and_entities.put("something", Pair.of("left", "right"))
URL_and_entities.get("something").getLeft();
URL_and_entities.get("something").getRight();
```

Comment: how to iterate over that? I need to iterate thru it and then pull out the URL and both entities.

Comment: You can iterate the map and get the `Pair` object, use the `getLeft` and `getRight` to get values.

Comment: how to get just the url, i.e. `something`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Map<String,String> entities; 

for (String entity_1 : Q_value_references_for_sentence_entities) 
{
   for (String entity_2 : Q_value_references_for_sentence_entities) 
    {
       entities = new HashMap<String, String>();
       entities.put(entity_1, entity_2);

       ...check that URL exist and doesn't return null, and then convert it to a String...

       URL_and_entities.put(output, entities);
       }
    }
}
```

I don't understand though, why you are using a Map to store the two entities. Unless you plan on using one entity to reference the second entity, you can simply store the two entities in a simple array (or technically even an ArrayList or HashSet would be better than a Map).

Just do:

```
Map<String, String[]> URL_and_entities = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
String [] entities = new String[2];

for (String entity_1 : Q_value_references_for_sentence_entities) 
{
   for (String entity_2 : Q_value_references_for_sentence_entities) 
    {
       entities[0] = entity_1;
       entities[1] = entity_2;

       ...check that URL exist and doesn't return null, and then convert it to a String...

       URL_and_entities.put(output, entities);
       }
    }
}
```

Then to retrieve and print all the values in the set you just do:

```
   for (String url: byLetter.keySet()) {
        String [] retrievedValues = URL_and_entities.get(url);
        System.out.println(url + " " + retrievedValues[0] + ", " + retrievedValues[1];
    }
```

If using an ArrayList do:

```
   for (String url: byLetter.keySet()) {
        ArrayList retrievedValues = URL_and_entities.get(url);
        System.out.println(url + " " + retrievedValues.get(0) + ", " + retrievedValues.get(1);
    }
```

Comment: actually, this sounds very reasonable. tho for some reason my IDE doesn't like this :`String[2]>();`

Comment: I just used an array list, but could you show me how I could get the entities back out?

Comment: If you will always only have 2 entities, there is no reason to use an ArrayList, which is a more complex data structure then an array, when you can get away with using a simple array.

Comment: seems now I'm getting a null pointer expection on the code for getting the values out of the array list?  [this](https://github.com/h1395010/database_builder/blob/master/src/main/java/Q/Label_Assigner.java) is my program, do you think, maybe you might take a look? perhaps you could tell better than me why thats happening

Comment: change `for (Entry<String, ArrayList<String>> url : URL_and_entities.entrySet())` on line 229 to for `(String url : URL_and_entities.keySet())`. Your URL_and_entities Map has Strings for keys, not Entry Objects. When you try to retrieve a value from a Map, if the Map cannot find a matching key, it just returns null. If you send in a Entry url instead of a String, the result will always be null since the Map does not contain any Entry values. Therefore, your ArrayList in 246 will always get the value of null.